# Accessing <object> parent from children html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html files:

parent.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Parent</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <object data="child.html" data-message="hello"></object>
        <object data="child.html" data-message="world"></object>
    </body>

</html>
```

child.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Child</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="alert('hello world');">press me</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

I would like that pressing the button rendered by the first object element will alert the data-message of its parent ("hello"). The same for the second button, rendered by the second object with the second message ("world").

Consider that I can only work on the scripts in the child.html file.

Comment: Can we first know why you are using an object?

Comment: Because we have to integrate the work of two companies. The first one will work on the parent.html while the second (which is mine) will work on the child.html.

Comment: If from same origin, Ajax the pages into a div

Comment: in which sense iframe is better than object?

Comment: [`iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) would be more specific than [`object`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element), but the spec clearly says `object` can be used this way, so I think my comment was mistaken. I don't know that I've ever seen `object` used that way, though, whereas `iframe` is used that way all the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to have the other company change `parent.html` some; if you don't, and there are really multiple `child.html` references in the parent HTML, the child window can't tell which one relates to it. The child windows have access to the parent window, but not to the element (`object` or `iframe`) that contains them.

If it's just a message, have the other company pass the message to the child on the query string rather than as a `data-message` attribute:

```
<object data="child.html?hello"></object>
<object data="child.html?world"></object>
```

Then:

```
alert(location.search.substring(1));
```

But I assume it's about more than just the message.

So you'll have to have the other company put *some* kind of marker on the `object` or `iframe` that allows you to tell one from the other.

For example:

```
<object data="child.html?1" data-child="1" data-message="hello"></object>
<object data="child.html?2" data-child="2" data-message="world"></object>
```

Then in `child.html`, you can do this when handling the button click:

```
var childId = location.search.substring(1);
var element = parent.document.querySelector("[data-child='" + childId + "']");
var message = element.getAttribute("data-message");
alert(message);
```

or as a one-liner:

```
alert(parent.document.querySelector("[data-child='" + location.search.substring(1) + "']").getAttribute("data-message"));
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 (provided IE11 isn't in "compatibility" mode).